# PSQL query to return results where creationdate is within the most recent week

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, psql

I have this PSQL query:

```
 SELECT status, username, jobname, creationdate FROM t_job WHERE jobname = 'Loadon';
```

which gives me this data (sample first 3 lines):

```
 succeeded   | danielp      | Loadon  | 2018-03-20 12:30:25.655+11
 succeeded   | philm        | Loadon  | 2018-03-05 15:18:50.225+11
 succeeded   | garethy      | Loadon  | 2018-03-16 17:09:23.596+11
```

I need to add a date condition to my WHERE statement so that I only get results that were within the most recent week, starting on Monday. So if today is Thursday I need all results from Monday-Thursday.

I'm not sure what date features PSQL has or how to use it, and how to read my creationdate strings as an actual date that can be compared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `date_trunc()`:

```
SELECT status, username, jobname, creationdate
FROM t_job
WHERE jobname = 'Loadon' AND
      creationdate >= datetrunc('week', current_date);
```

Weeks are defined as starting on Monday, which is exactly what you want.